# UHD vs HDR vs QLED vs?

Tags: television, hdtv, home-electronics, led, uhd

Okay so I just received the dreaded single pixel line down the center of my main TV and decided it was time to buy a new one.  I am now overwhelmed confused and ready to start reading more.

I am looking for a TV with the following qualifications:

- Basic set of ports such as HDMI
- 65-75" in size
- Good for all around use TV / Movies no gaming or PC Use

Budget: Open - I can afford anything up to say $4000 but would like to spend as little as possible.

Smart / Internet Connected: Optional but if it is internet connected I would like for it to be wireless.

All of the above covers just about every option.  Where I need some help with recommendations is all the terminology.

The ranges of these TVs start at about $850 for a known brand but goes all the way up to $5000 +

There is UHD and HDR and QLED and OLED and what seems like a million others.

What should I be focused on and does anyone have any good recommendations for a good all around general use TV.

Comment: http://www.lg.com/uk/tvs/lg-OLED65G6V seems like a quality choice, and they are market leaders in top of the range equipment.

Comment: Yeah I looked at that one then red a bunch of reviews about screen burn in.

Comment: might have changed their technology more recently to be fair. I would definitely look at an LG or Samsung option if you are set on 4k OLED/Quantam Dot TV